# On the complexity of global fields isomorphism

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, function-fields

Let $L$ and $K$ be isomorphic global fields (i.e. either function fields of curves over a finite field, or number fields). What is the complexity of finding an isomorphism between them? Is there a polynomial time algorithm?
Notice that the assumption is that $L$ and $K$ are isomorphic simply as fields.